# VB.net Calculator in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to coding entirely. I am attempting to create an event procedure where a button click in access adds together 6 fields which are each independently variable and have no idea why the process is failing. I don't even receive an error when I click the calculate box in Access that the event procedure is tied to. Here is what I have so far.

Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub CalculateButton_Click()

    Dim TotalIncomeAmt As Integer
    Dim TotalSocialSecurityIncomeAmt As Integer
    Dim TotalSocialSecurityBenefitAmt As Integer
    Dim TotalChildSupportAmt As Integer
    Dim TotalFoodStampAmt As Integer
    Dim TotalOtherIncomeAmt As Integer
    Dim GrandTotalIncome As Integer

    If IFW - How_often_received = "Weekly" Then
        TotalIncomeAmt = IFW_Amount * 4.25
    End If
    If IFW - How_often_received = "Bi-Monthly" Then
        TotalIncomeAmt = IFW_Amount * 2
    End If
    If IFW - How_often_received = "Monthly" Then
        TotalIncomeAmt = IFW_Amount
    End If
    If IFW - How_often_received = " " Then
        TotalIncomeAmt = 0
    End If

    If SSI - How_often_received = "Weekly" Then
        TotalSocialSecurityIncomeAmt = SSI_Amount * 4.25
    End If
    If SSI - How_often_received = "Bi-Monthly" Then
        TotalSocialSecurityIncomeAmt = SSI_Amount * 2
    End If
    If SSI - How_often_received = "Monthly" Then
        TotalSocialSecurityIncomeAmt = SSI_Amount
    End If
    If SSI - How_often_received = " " Then
        TotalSocialSecurityIncomeAmt = 0
    End If

    If SSB - How_often_received = "Weekly" Then
        TotalSocialSecurityBenefitAmt = SSB_Amount * 4.25
    End If
    If SSI - How_often_received = "Bi-Monthly" Then
        TotalSocialSecurityBenefitAmt = SSB_Amount * 2
    End If
    If SSI - How_often_received = "Monthly" Then
        TotalSocialSecurityBenefitAmt = SSB_Amount
    End If
    If SSI - How_often_received = " " Then
        TotalSocialSecurityBenefitAmt = 0
    End If

    If CH - How_often_received = "Weekly" Then
        TotalChildSupportAmt = CH_Amount * 4.25
    End If
    If CH - How_often_received = "Bi-Monthly" Then
        TotalChildSupportAmt = CH_Amount * 2
    End If
    If CH - How_often_received = "Monthly" Then
        TotalChildSupportAmt = CH_Amount
    End If
    If CH - How_often_receive_benefits = " " Then
        TotalChildSupportAmt = 0
    End If

    If FS - How_often_received = "Weekly" Then
        TotalFoodStampAmt = FS_Dollar_Amount * 4.25
    End If
    If FS - How_often_received = "Bi-Monthly" Then
        TotalFoodStampAmt = FS_Dollar_Amount * 2
    End If
    If FS - How_often_received = "Monthly" Then
        TotalFoodStampAmt = FS_Dollar_Amount
    End If
    If FS - How_often_received = " " Then
        TotalFoodStampAmt = 0
    End If

    If OI - How_often_received = "Weekly" Then
        TotalOtherIncomeAmt = OI_Amount * 4.25
    End If
    If OI - How_often_received = "Bi-Monthly" Then
        TotalOtherIncomeAmt = OI_Amount * 2
    End If
    If OI - How_often_received = "Monthly" Then
        TotalOtherIncomeAmt = OI_Amount
    End If
    If OI - How_often_received = "None" Then
        TotalOtherIncomeAmt = 0
    End If

    GrandTotalIncome = (TotalIncomeAmt + TotalBenefitsAmt + TotalFoodStampAmt + TotalChildSupportAmt + TotalOtherIncomeAmt)
    Total_Monthly_Income = GrandTotalIncome
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't the weekly calculation be done with `0.25`?

Comment: what does this means `IFW - How_often_received = "Weekly"` ??? What I read is : Substract `IFW` from `How_often_received` and compare the result to the string `Weekly`. This has no sense to me. You've got this all over the place.

Comment: What @ThomasG pointed out was the first thing that popped up as needing to be revisited. The second you may want to reconsider is the possibility that multiple conditions could be true. If that is the case then you want to change: `TotalIncomeAmt = IFW_Amount * 4.25` to `TotalIncomeAmt  = TotalIncomeAmt + (IFW_Amount * 4.25)`

Comment: Each If statement references a drop down box in access where the options are " ";"weekly; Bi-Monthly; Monthly. I am seeking to find at total monthly income which is the weekly amount is being multiplied by 4.25.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
Dim GrandTotalIncome As Currency
Dim Factor As Currency
```

Then revise all the code blocks like this:

```
Dim TotalIncomeAmt As Currency ' To hold decimals
' Also, IFW_Amount must be Currency.


Select Case [IFW - How_often_received]
    Case "Weekly" 
        Factor = 4.25
    Case "Bi-Monthly" 
        Factor = 2
    Case "Monthly" 
        Factor = 1
    Case Else
        Factor = 0
End Select
TotalIncomeAmt = IFW_Amount * Factor
```